# How to modify this php function to check all lines before result execution?

Tags: php, function, line, execution

I have corrected a code,whice should only echo all 'lines' containing word "TrxID",from file.html. but it is returns first of the 'paragraph' amongst them whice contains "TrxID", thus there are more than 3 lines contains "TrxID".

File.html

```
    <html lang="en"> <body> <p> recieved $500<br /> to 862444947 successful<br /> Fee $ 9<br />25<br /> Balance Tk $1000<br />78<br /> TrxID 6DU2ATVQCO at 30/04/2019 19:25<br />download the app </p>

  <p> recieved $500<br /> to 862444947 successful<br /> Fee $ 9<br />25<br /> Balance Tk $1000<br />78<br /> Tr 6DU2ATVQCO at 30/04/2019 19:25<br />download the app </p>

  <p> recieved $500<br /> to 862444947 successful<br /> Fee $ 9<br />25<br /> Balance Tk $1000<br />78<br /> TrxID 6DU2ATVQgfCO at 30/04/2019 19:25<br />download the app </p>

  <p> recieved $500<br /> to 862444947 successful<br /> Fee $ 9<br />25<br /> Balance Tk $1000<br />78<br /> 6DU2ATVQCO at 30/04/2019 19:25<br />download the app </p> </body> </html>
```

Function.php

```
   <?php  function checkFile( $file, $keyword ) {

// open file for reading
$handle = @fopen( $file, 'r' );

// check to make sure handle is valid
if( $handle ) {

    // traverse file line by line
    while( ($line = fgets($handle)) !== false ) {

        // search for specific keyword no matter what case is used i.e. trxid or TrxID
        if( stripos($line, $keyword) === false ) {
            // string not found, continue with next iteration
            continue;
        } else {

            // keyword was found

            // close file
            fclose($handle);

            // return line
            return $line;
        }
    }
} } $result = checkFile( 'file.html', 'TrxID' );  echo $result; ?>
```

Result

```
recieved $500 to 862444947 successful Fee $ 9 25 Balance Tk $1000 78 TrxID 6DU2ATVQCO at 30/04/2019 19:25 download the app
```

I want :

```
TrxID 6DU2ATVQCO at 30/04/2019 19:25
```

Now I want to make sure,

1. It should only returns line contains 'TRXID',Not paragraph,if I replace br/ with 'paragraph tag' result remains same
2. It should show all lines,just not a single result.on this function it just returns the first not all.

Hoping your help.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code a little:

```
function checkFile($file, $keyword)
{
    $handle = @fopen($file, 'r');
    if ($handle) {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            if (stripos($line, $keyword) === false) {
                continue;
            } else {
                $exploded = explode('<br />', $line);
                foreach ($exploded as $e) {
                    if (stripos($e, $keyword) !== false) {
                        $lines[] = substr($e, 0, strpos($e, "at"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $lines;
    fclose($handle);
}
$result = checkFile('file.html', 'TrxID');
print_r($result); // return array of lines
```

or if you want to echo it :

`echo $output = implode('<br />', $result);`

If you want just string after trxid:

```
function checkFile($file, $keyword)
{
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($file);
    $result = preg_match_all('/(?<=\b'.$keyword.'\s)(?:[\w-]+)/is', $fileContents, $matches);
    return preg_filter('/^/', $keyword.' ', $matches[0]);
}

$result = checkFile('file.html', 'TrxID');
print_r($result); // return array of lines
```

Comment: Mike ,it works, but is it case sensitive?cause if I change one of TrxID To trxid, the result of trxid isn't showing!!?

Comment: I edited code, you can try now. Just change strpos to stripos.

Comment: Mike,what change do you recommend if I only want to get "TrxID 6DU2ATVQCO "  instead of "TrxID 6DU2ATVQCO at 30/04/2019 19:25"?

Comment: Actually, it is working half of my expectation now it is returning     : " recieved $500 to 862444947 successfulv Fee $ 92.5 Balance Tk $1000 78  TrxID 6DU2ATVQCO "   NOT : "TrxID 6DU2ATVQCO",Any suggestion how to do it? ;-)

Comment: can you post your file.html ? For me, its working and return : TrxID 6DU2ATVQCO

Edit: I added other code to my answer, if you want just string after trxid, but both are working

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is that you could pass the entire file contents into preg_match and you will be returned an array of matching items inside $matches.

```
$result = preg_match('/TrxID .+ at [\d]{2}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{4} [\d]{2}:[\d]{2}/i', $fileContents, $matches)

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: It beautiful colonelclick,I tried with preg_match but failed, that was my mistake. But these codes are necessary because I completed my project without fixing it!! If   I am going to change that to your then I have to make more edit,whice I didn't want,but I will remember your suggestion.  :-)